# matlab's FFT is wrong? don't think so

Tags: matlab, fft, phase

i'm trying to get an FFT of a signal

my FFT has 1024 samples

i added two sin functions one of freq 86,13Hz (2*44100/1024) and one of freq 129,19Hz (3*44100/1024)

the WAV looks like that (for 1 period) :

[image]

i then use this code to inspect the FFT

```
FFTSize = 1024;

Y = wavread('2sins.wav');

current_window = zeros(FFTSize, 1);

for k = 1:length(Y)/(FFTSize)

   for m = 1:FFTSize
       current_window(m, 1) = Y((k-1)*(FFTSize)+m, 1);
   end;

   plot(current_window)

   a = abs(Ydft);
   p = angle(Ydft);

  end;
```

the bins 2 and 3 have the maximum amplitude of 256 which is right as i used two sin of frequency 2 and 3

[image]

but when i look at the phases they are -pi/2 which is weird as they should be 0 no ?

here are the phases :

[image]

so you see they are -pi/2, why is that ?

and here is the WAV file i used so you can try yourself:
http://www.khaelis.com/tmp/2sins.zip

thanks for help

Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab is right, as usually. The DFT of a sine is imaginary. If you do the same with the sum of two cosines, you would get a real-valued result.

Comment: i thought DFT was decomposing the signal in sinuses not cosinuses

Comment: @ionone, neither. It decomposes into complex exponentials $\exp(i \omega) = \cos(\omega) + i \sin(\omega)$

Comment: yes but when i have the phase and magnitude, they represent what ? sinuses or cosinuses ?

Comment: oh i get it : DCT = discrete COS transform but originally the FT was with sinuses ...get it now